# Capacitor charging due to battery

Tags: capacitor

I recently saw a video on khan academy which states that a capacitor acts like an open circuit. The video also states that the anode of the battery repels electrons and the cathode of the battery attracts electrons. How is that possible? I mean that electric potential provided by a electrochemical cell is the amount of energy per unit charge which comes from redox reactions. If the circuit is open there would be no redox reactions!

Comment: Could you please update your question with a link to the video?

Comment: "the anode of the battery repels electrons ans the cathode of the battery" - huh?

Comment: Sorry I cant Im using my cellphone and I dont have a laptop on my own:(

Comment: No, a capacitor acts like a capacitor all the time. Sometimes that's an open circuit, sometimes a short circuit, and most of the time something much more interesting. Taking a model of a battery, and then trying to reason from the model, is usually doooooomed to failure. Models, like 'repels electrons' are like little sketch-maps of reality. You wouldn't scrawl a sketch map on the back of an envelope, and then start using that to say you didn't understand how your streets were layed out. Physics is usually easiest if you track the energy, so go for your redox reactions!

Comment: I found something on wikipedia:it says when a dialetric is placed in an electric field(obviously on our occasion battery's electric field)the molecules get electric dipole moment and the material is polarized.Is this what am I looking for?